# Creating a grid in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I though this would be simple to do (or find an answer for) but I am running into a problem and I could not find a response online (feel free to link the post where there is the answer).

I am trying to display nodes over a 2 x 3 grid. Here is the code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\idx{0}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,1}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\idx}{\idx+1};
            \node[circle, draw] (\idx) at (\i*2,\j*1.5) {$\idx$};
        }
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is the counter not updating? The output is a right 2 x 3 grid, but with just 1 inside every node.

Comment: `\foreach` puts the stuff it is iterating over in groups, and the definitions are local, so get "forgotten".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\foreach` puts the stuff it is iterating over in groups, and the definitions are local, so get "forgotten". You could just make the macro global, however that's not good practice. So you could just introduce a count.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i [count=\counti starting from 0] in {0,...,2}{
        \foreach \j [count=\countj starting from 0] in {0,...,1}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\idx}{1+2*\counti+\countj}
            \node[circle, draw] (\idx) at (\i*2,\j*1.5) {$\idx$};
        }
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or just use `\i` and `\j` directly

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {0,...,2}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,1}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\idx}{1+2*\i+\j}
            \node[circle, draw] (\idx) at (\i*2,\j*1.5) {$\idx$};
        }
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use a LaTeX counter, which is global by default.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\newcounter{idx}
\setcounter{idx}{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {0,...,2}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,1}{
            \stepcounter{idx}
            \node[circle, draw] (\number\value{idx}) at (\i*2,\j*1.5) {$\arabic{idx}$};
        }
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the options. Yes, I have also though about the second way, but I wanted to understand how to use a global index. This shows all options. Great!